# A partition does not have rw permissions

Tags: partitioning, sudo

A partition in my system has no reading writing rights, it always needs `sudo` permission. How to make it regularly accessible without `sudo`?

---

This is the output of `lsblk -fs -d -p -m -I 3,8,66,67,68` -

```
NAME      FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT NAME       SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
/dev/sda1 vfat   ESP    2877-2A33                            /boot/efi  /dev/sda1  600M root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sda2 vfat   OS     2AC3-1F88                                       /dev/sda2    3G root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sda3 ext4   UBUNTU b838e318-4ded-423a-b03e-f41d3613056b /          /dev/sda3 69.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sda4 swap          07c2b983-ef39-4d69-84c9-de1f8e649986 [SWAP]     /dev/sda4 14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sda5 ext4          1e8494eb-8d8b-4ce1-9621-c0e625e38361            /dev/sda5 65.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sda6 ext4          65899ea6-e053-48dc-9ad8-8fad389eeaca /media/ubu /dev/sda6  778G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

Comment: You haven't given us much, if it's a posix compatible file-system, maybe your $UID isn't valid for the files that are stored there etc...  I'd look at your `mount` output for clues, as currently we can only guess at why (too few details)

Comment: @guiverc sorry for that, but I really don't know much about the system as well as the working of ubuntu yet. Please check the edit.

Comment: By `mount` I meant the command used to mount your partition  (the commands shows the output directly after command entry unless perfectly clean; if GUI is used you get the detail from logs), however what you did provide shows a $UID of 1001, where the default user is 1000 so it could be the $UID as I mentioned.  But I'd still be guessing as you provided no details as to how mounted (command and output etc), type of file-system etc.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate more on what exactly do you want and how can I provide those details?

Comment: Please add info : copy/paste the output of `lsblk -fs -T -d -p -m -I 3,8,66,67,68`

Comment: How do you mount your partition, a command (if so what's the command), a fstab entry (what is the entry) etc...

Comment: @cmak.fr it says `invalid option -- 'T'`. When I removed it, I got something which I've added in the question.

Comment: Which partition has no read/write permissions? Is the the last one in the table, '/dev/sda6` mounted on `/media/ubu...`? Or is it `/dev/sda2`, the `vfat` partition or another one?

Comment: The last one. sda6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition `/dev/sda6` has the 'ext4` file system. This is a linux file system, and you can manage the ownership and permissions individually for each directory and file.

I suggest that you do a basic configuaration:

- Create a directory in the partition at the mountpoint `/media/ubu...` (use the complete path).

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/ubu.../data
  ```
- Set the desired owner of this directory, for example `"$USER"`.

  ```
  sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /media/ubu.../data
  ```
- Maybe change the permissions of this directory, but the defaults might work for you, when you own it.

  ```
  chmod ...  /media/ubu.../data
  ```

---

Now you should be able to read and write in this 'data' directory in your partition `/dev/sda6`.

If there are still problems, please describe them, and I will try to help ...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I just have a question, how to identify the mountpoint?. As per your instructions I issued two commands. 1) `sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu/65899ea6-e053-48dc-9ad8-8fad389eeaca/ubuntu/data` 2) `sudo chown "$ubuntu":"$ubuntu" /media/ubuntu/65899ea6-e053-48dc-9ad8-8fad389eeaca/ubuntu/data`. `ubuntu` is my username. Process exited normally without errors, but no directory was formed. What must be the reason?

Comment: Try `sudo lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint` to identify the mountpoint. and do it in a terminal window that is wide enough to leave some free space behind the last line of output.

Comment: And I am supposed to change both of the "$USER":"$USER" with my username, right?

Comment: You can do that, but `"$USER"`should resolve to your username automatically.

Comment: Ok. Now I've done that, does it require a reboot to be in effect?

Comment: I don't think so. Please try to create a file in the directory 'data' and after that try to read that file. It should work. -- If you have directories and files in the partition already, you can move them into 'data' or simply change owner of all these files where they are. You can use `sudo chown` with the option '-R` to recurse to modify all directories and files. **Warning: double-check that you will do this in the correct partition, `/dev/sda6`**. Otherwise you can cause great damage and get a corrupted operating system that is difficult to repair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99837/discussion-between-niranjan-and-sudodus).